# Uncaught TypeError: _firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.registerVersion is not a function in IONIC v4

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, webpack, ionic4

**problem**

when run/deploy the app  (ionic serve) 
in the console see this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: _firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.registerVersion is not a function
    at auth.esm.js:372
    at auth.esm.js:372
    at Module.<anonymous> (auth.esm.js:372)
    at Module../node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.esm.js (auth.esm.js:374)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../node_modules/firebase/auth/dist/index.esm.js (index.esm.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/auth.module.js (auth.module.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/fire/auth/public_api.js (public_api.js:1)
```

the  auth.esm.js file shows in the end of file this line of code with error underling

```
;firebase.registerVersion("@firebase/auth","0.13.3");firebase.INTERNAL.extendNamespace({User:Q})}else throw Error("Cannot find the firebase namespace; be sure to include firebase-app.js before this library.");})();}).apply(typeof global !== 'undefined' ? global : typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window : {});
```

**environment**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.13 (C:\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.5.3, (and 11 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.3.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (E:\ANDROID_SDK)
   NodeJS            : v12.14.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.13.4
   OS    

        : Windows 10
```

Updated
**webpack.config.js.**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'window.SQL': 'sql.js/js/sql.js'
        }),
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/typeorm$/, function (result) {
            result.request = result.request.replace(/typeorm/, "typeorm/browser");
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /\/package-name\//,
            (data) => {
                delete data.dependencies[0].critical;
                return data;
            },
        ),
        // new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/, path.join(__dirname, './client'))
    ],
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },
    externals: {
        'react-native-sqlite-storage': 'react-native-sqlite-storage'
    }
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxx.xxxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "xxxx",
  "homepage": "https://xxxx.com.ar/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.4.25",
    "@firebase/polyfill": "^0.3.29",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^5.19.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-resizer": "4.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-audio": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^5.17.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.11.7",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.25.36",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "cordova": "^8.1.2",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-browsertab": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplayservices": "^19.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.5.3",
    "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio": "^3.0.9",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^7.5.0",
    "imagemin": "^5.3.1",
    "info.protonet.imageresizer": "^0.1.1",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.9",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "local-storage": "^1.4.2",
    "moment": "^1.7.2",
    "ng-lottie": "^0.3.2",
    "ng2-reactive-forms-validators": "^1.1.0",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^8.1.6",
    "ngx-mask-ionic": "^1.1.2",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "sql.js": "^0.5.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.8",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.20",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.2.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.19",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  },
  "description": " ",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxx-xxxxxxx",
        "WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID": "xxxxx-XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {
        "FCM_CORE_VERSION": "16.0.9",
        "FCM_VERSION": "18.0.0",
        "GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION": "3.5.0",
        "GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "4.2.0"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

**info**

The only thing that I see is that the version of @firebase/app in package is ^0.4.25 . And in auth the version is 0.13.3

**What I already done**

- delete node_modules, and package.json-lock and run npm i several times
- run the npm cache clean --force

Comment: could be @ionic-native/image-resizer version, as it is using 4 instead of 5.

Comment: @JavierAviles sorry but same error even if I removed the dependency. This dependency is not related to the issue.

Comment: I do think it is related to the module output format set by webpack. Do you have any webpack config file on your project?

Comment: @KingDarBoja  
yes, I've updated this issue with more info

Comment: You want to configure firebase with ionic ? and you are facing this issue . @exequielc

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama yes, firebase fcm & ionic

Comment: @exequielc , look at the answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure firebase in ionic using the following steps ,

```
npm install @angular/fire firebase --save
```

Once AngularFire has been installed (the plugin that we’ll use to communicate our Ionic app with Firebase), we need to create a new project in Firebase. To create a project, go to the [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/?pli=1), where you’ll see the options to create project:

**Later**

 We’ll specify these credentials to tell our Ionic application to communicate with our Firebase application.
[image]
The next step will be to add our Firebase credentials to our Ionic application. For this we’ll go to our Ionic project, which we created in the previous step, and add the following code in the environment.ts file located in `src/environments/`:

```
export const environment = {
 production: false,
 firebase: {
   apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
   authDomain: "YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN",
   databaseURL: "YOUR_DATABASE_URL",
   projectId: "YOUR_PROJECT_ID",
   storageBucket: "YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET",
   messagingSenderId: "YOUR_SENDER_ID"
 }
};
```

*Keep in mind that you have to replace the constants with your own values.*
Add This Code in your `app.module.ts`

```
    import { AngularFireModule  } from '@angular/fire';
    import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase), //add this code 
    AngularFireDatabaseModule  //add this code 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Through this, you can configure your ionic app with firebase.